# Why Arduino Mega 2560 throw error when i try to upload example

Tags: usb, atmega2560

I'm try to connect my Arduino Mega 2560 to PC, but I think it's not easy as I imagine. I spent a lot's of time to install USB driver. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Device manager]

When I try to upload blink example, Arduino IDE throw this error:

```
Sketch uses 656 bytes (0%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 8183 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\\.\COM10"
avrdude: ser_drain(): read error: The handle is invalid."
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Please help to run one simple example.

I think this screen may help to understand my problem:

[image: COM port selection]

Comment: Did you reboot your PC after installing drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I install driver for this site and everything is working well.
driver download:  wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html

I'm recommend to unplug arduino first and install driver, after that plug and enjoy.

Here is a video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhmG5J-AHrg

Comment: So - you don't have a genuine Arduino then... Some cheap far-east inferior quality clone...

Comment: Tried everything but in the end these Chinese drivers works. Yes its not a genuine arduino. but its open source and anybody can make and manufacture it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is:

- Use another USB port
- Reopen IDE
- Reinsert the USB cable
- Use a different USB cable
- Prevent using a USB 'box' in between
- Try a different 2560 (if you have)
- Restart computer
- Check if it can be found in the system drivers
- Reinstall IDE (after deinstall it).

However, as the author already mentioned the real solution is needed for some non-genuine Arduinos:

- Install the CH driver e.g. at wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html

Comment: I do everything(but not change other arduino) but does not meter, I think USB driver is not install correctly.

Comment: In that case the last option should fix it (maybe deinstall IDE first just for certainty)

Comment: ok, I'll try it one more time. but, I think best way to fix this issue is throw arduino into trash

Comment: nothing change, IDE can not connect to device.

Comment: You can also try another USB port and restarting the computer.

Comment: I'm installing this : http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html
and left only this problem: "Sketch uses 1462 bytes (0%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 8183 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes."

Comment: @AvtandilKavrelishvili You should put this as your answer ... some Chinese products do not use the same officially Arduino components and this driver is needed to install in addition.

Comment: Btw, the other message about the memory is not a problem, it just says you use 0% (or at least negigible) amount of flash memory and 9 bytes of dynamic memory ... so plenty left to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. Then I un-plugged my connections and pressed the reset button. Then I uploaded the default blink example to my board. Then it's working fine. Then again I made a connection to the board and it shows the same error again. Now, I un-plugged the GND pin; it's working again. So, in my case there was some thing wrong with my connections.